# how to add dynamicity in a variable value in jenkins groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

i have a json file like the below one..

```
{
   "env1":{
      "region":{
         "region1":{
            "var1":"test"
         },
         "region2":{
            "var1":"test"
         },
         "region3":{
            "var1":"test"
         }
      }
   },
   "env2":{
      "region":{
         "region1":{
            "var1":"test"
         },
         "region2":{
            "var1":"test"
         },
         "region3":{
            "var1":"test"
         }
      }
   }
}

config_all = readJSON file: "${env.WORKSPACE}/<above-json-name>.json"
```

my concern is how do i dynamically get the config for different region at runtime..
i want to do something like this  based on  a variable..

```
def region = env.getProperty("region")
config = config_all.env2.${region}  << something like this.. but i cannot aceive it..
```

is there a way to aceive this sort of dynamicity in the varilable value assignment in jenkins groovy.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access values in a map with dynamic/variable keys, then you cannot use the object syntax, but rather must use the native syntax for accessing values from keys in a Map with `[<key>]`.

Following this, we update your code snippet like:

```
config = config_all['env2'][region]
```

However, based on your JSON, that is probably not going to traverse your data correctly since it is missing the top-level `region` key and the `var1` key. In that case, it would more likely need to be:

```
config = config_all['env2']['region'][region]['var1']
```

That will assign the value `test` to your variable `config`.